# Why do type guards behave differently when using Partial mapped types in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Compilation of the following code using `tsc --strictNullChecks` fails with `error TS2339: Property 'name' does not exist on type '{}'`.

```
type Obj = {} | undefined;

type User = {
  email: string;
  password: string;
  name: string;
};

type PartialUser = Partial<User>;

function isUser(obj: Obj): obj is PartialUser {
  return true;
}

function getUserName(obj: Obj) {
  if (isUser(obj)) {
    return obj.name;
  }

  return '';
}
```

However, if I replace `type PartialUser = Partial<User>;` with

```
type PartialUser = {
  email?: string;
  password?: string;
  name?: string;
};
```

everything is hunky-dory.

There are a few workarounds available, but I'm curious why this would be the case. Shouldn't these two definitions of PartialUser be functionally equivalent? I'm on Version 3.1.3

Comment: Wierd... I'd report it as a bug in github.com if no one else here has any ideas

Comment: My sense is that type guards either narrow a type by filtering union constituents, or by producing [intersections](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/9031).   In this case you *want* an intersection (like `PartialUser & Obj`) but you're *getting* a union filter (like `{}`).   I've never fully understood the heuristics for when it chooses an intersection vs a union filter.. something to do with whether the types are "unrelated". It must think `Partial<User>` is "related" to `Obj` but the manual `PartialUser` is "unrelated".  Not sure why though.

Comment: Looks to me like you've found a bug in TypeScript - congratulations!

Comment: crosslinking with GitHub for interested parties: [Microsoft/TypeScript#28434](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28434)

Answer (score 1):

The difference here should be fixed by https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29384